# Reverse TakeUntil logic using RX.NET

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

First off, for full disclosure I'm a n00b in RX, but I'm learning daily now...

I need to build an Observable that's going to enable a button (or automatically start an action) as long as a stream of another incoming observable averaged signals is coming in within a certain range. As far as I've learned so far, I could do that by adding a .Where to an averaged Observable in which I can then check that my observed average values created from an event handler are in fact within a given range...

What I need also however is to have these observable values influence the state of my action/button (allow it to be executed) just until its underlying/inner signals overstep the given range. Is such a thing in RX possible as a reversed .TakeUntil(inverse where clause) which I now think could maybe solve my problem, or should I just reuse the original observable and copy it with a negated .Where clause and then use that as another independent observable...if latter, is there some performance loss by reusing almost identical observables multiple times, just changing few their linq queries...how many observables is too much please?

Comment: Are you asking for a button to be enabled if the values of an observable are within a certain range and disabled if they are not? Is it as simple as that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that something like this is sufficient.

```
var source = Observable.Range(0, 10);

var query =
    source
        .Buffer(4, 1)
        .Select(xs => xs.Average())
        .Select(x => x > 5.0 && x <= 7.0);

query.ObservableOn(button).Subscribe(enabled => button.Enabled = enabled);
```

(I've assumed Windows forms.)

This gives me:

```
False
False
False
False
True
True
False
False
False
False
```

I can improve it slightly like this:

```
var query =
    source
        .Buffer(4, 1)
        .Select(xs => xs.Average())
        .Select(x => x > 5.0 && x <= 7.0)
        .StartWith(true)
        .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

That then gives me:

```
True
False
True
False
```

Please let me know if I've missed anything.